# Pros and con of $.ajax, $.load, $.getscript and object tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery, web

I am using strict doctype and i want to embed a page within a page, for this i cannot use iframe as the doctype is strict , so found out 4 methods:

- `$.ajax()`
- `.load()`
- `$.getscript`
- `<object>` tag

can any one please tell me about the pros and con of all these approaches..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i'll attempt to answer this one.

- [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is the root method of jQuery for ajax requests. it is so detailed, you have a lot of parameters to configure it (mostly, they are left as default). this complexity gave rise to the common [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shorthands for easy use. [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is what you use if you want fine-grained control of the ajax request and what you want to do with it after.
- [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a "subfunction" of [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (it uses get) but is has an implicit callback (aside from an optional callback). it instead loads the requested page, and places it in the element that precedes it <s>as an escaped mark-up</s>. this is good for loading pages that are already formatted to load into the target container.
- [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is NOT meant to load pages. it's to retrieve scripts and execute them on the page.
- [`<object>`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/object) tags however...

  > The object element’s purpose is to embed into a document a variety of different kinds of media files. **Historically, it was used primarily for placing ActiveX controls onto a page**, but it *can also be used to embed images (.gif, .jpg, and so on), movie files and applets, video files, PDF documents, Flash*, and even HTML.

  although it can render HTML, it's not it's original purpose. It's meant for *other* media.

---

personally, i go for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to return JSON data and an HTML template, then have a template engine to build the page. this way, JSON is light on the bandwidth, and templates are cacheable.

Comment: +1 on using JSON data + HTML template vs embedding HTML. Unless it's partial HTML fragments I can't see how embedded HTML is going to validate.

Comment: Update: consider ES7 async functions (await) too.